# Deployment with WebStorm (JetBrains) - sends only one file

Tags: webstorm, vps

I configure deployment setting in WebStorm to location on my VPS. When I'm trying deploy to VPS WebStorm sends only one file - index.html

I want to send all files (or recently updated like in version control).

I've checked configuration but can't find any settings let me choose file to send.

How to send all files to VPS?

Comment: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/10/deploying-committed-changes-to-a-remote-server/

Comment: Note : "The automatic upload process for a commit only transfers the current changeset’s files to the remote host. All preceding commits will be ignored by this process."

Comment: see also http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm

Comment: You can select desired files/folders and choose `Deploy to ...` from context menu .. or maybe even use  `Synch with deployed to...` to see how it differs from deployed version. http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/webinar-recording-deployment-with-phpstorm/

Answer (score 0):

Select the files and or folders you want to deploy in `Project Files` <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>. Right-click and select `Deployment -> Sync with Deployed to ...`. This will check the files and folders for differences with the remote host. Continuing with this dialog will upload (and download) the latest changes.

Be wary, this might take a while over FTP when processing large projects.